# Não mostrar erro 401 (Unauthorized) no console

Tags: angular, typescript

Criei um `api` usando o `passport do laravel 5.3`. Funciona da seguinte forma: O `angular 2` manda as credenciais para o `laravel`, é realizado a verificação e o `laravel` retorna um `token`. Está tudo funcionando redondo.

Algo que está me deixando descontente é quando as credenciais não são informadas corretamente. o Browser lança um erro no console. Eu já estou tratando tal erro e apresentando para o usuário. Mas queria que esse erro não aparecesse no console. vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro é:

> POST http://www.back.com.br/oauth/token 401 (Unauthorized)

Dei uma pesquisada no google e pelo que vi algumas pessoas falando isso não tem nada a ver com `angular 2`. Isso seria relacionado ao `laravel`.

enfim... alguém tem uma ideia de como retirar esse erro? acho deselegante.

Answer (score 1):

Quando sua API retorna o status 401 (Não autorizado), quem lida com o erro em vermelho no console é o navegador e não sua aplicação em sí, portanto não tem como não mostrar. Fora isso, tudo provavelmente está funcionando de acordo com o que deveria, ou seja, provavelmente as variáveis de resposta (body) está vindo corretamente do servidor, certo?

Se você quer evitar do console mostrar este erro, terá de escolher outro código de status para ser retornado pela API. Um código que não é enviado automaticamente como erro ao console pelo navegador.

Se eu fosse você, deixaria do jeito que está, pois é uma boa prática seguir corretamente os códigos de retorno, e pelo que vi na screenshot, está usando no momento certo. já que o erro "401 não autorizado" é um código correto para autenticação não realizada com sucesso.